# Include Library into XCode Project

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode, fmdb

I want to include the [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) library into an existing `XCode` Project. I know how to install it with `pods`. But is there a way to link it somehow with `Build Phases - Compile Sources` or `Build Phases - Link Binary with Libraries`? I am not sure how to do that, what files from `FMDB` to link, where to get the files, where to Drag & Drop what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply download this project first: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb
After extracting zip you see a folder under `fmdb/src`.Under `src` have another directory named `fmdb`. You need to drag this folder and drop into your project. Then you can easily access FMDB code.